# Define SSIS SMTP server connection from query

Tags: ssis

Hello is it possible to define the SMTP server address from a query in a SSIS package
I understand it might be through the expressions section [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUC7M.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason to do this through a query rather than a parameter?

Comment: No? I'm not sure of the best way of doing this. So whichever is better i'll do @MarkWojciechowicz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS provides a way of configuring packages with parameters so that they can run with different values in different environments.

In your case, right click the connection manager for the smtp server and select `parameterize...`.  In the dialogue, select the property, name the parameter and select whether you want it scoped to the project or package.  If you select project, other packages will be able to reuse it.

[image]

When this is finally deployed to the SSISDB catalog, you can configure the parameters in the sql agent job step or you can use `Environments` to preconfigure the project and packages.  Here are more details about parameters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-package-and-project-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16#parameterize-dialog-box